# lat must be a number when creating a GeoPoint

Tags: loopbackjs

I'm using Loopback 3.x. I got an error **lat must be a number when creating a GeoPoint** while creating a custom API for finding nearby doctors.

**user.json** file

```
"findNearByDoctors": {
  "accepts": [
    {
      "arg": "geoPoint",
      "type": "geopoint",
      "required": true,
      "description": "user's location"
    },
    {
      "arg": "range",
      "type": "number",
      "required": false,
      "description": "range"
    }
  ],
  "returns": [],
  "description": "find nearby doctors",
  "http": [
    {
      "path": "/get-nearby-doctors",
      "verb": "get"
    }
  ]
}
```

Input I given is

geoPoint: (1.28210155945393, 103.81722480263163)

Comment: Could you add a full request which produces an error?

Comment: I got the answer. geoPoint: {"lat": 1.28210155945393, "lng": 103.81722480263163}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

geoPoint: {"lat": 1.28210155945393, lng": 103.81722480263163}